# python tkinter gui window freeze after a while with arduino serial communication

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, pyserial

I am using pychem with tkinter gui for collecting data from arduino with serial communication and display on tkinter window. The script works fine at start but the tkinter gui window freeze and stop updating the values after a few minutes. After working on it for sometime, I realize the time it takes to freeze directly correlates to the number of data collected from arduino. If I send data every 0.1 s, the window freeze exactly after 8 min 30 sec and if I send data every 0.2 s, the time double almost to the second. Even after the window is freeze, the serial communication is still working fine and data are being collected by python script but just not updating on tkinter window.
Any advise is appreciated. I have been stacked on this for a while. I have tried threading but poses the same problem.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import time
import serial

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
ser = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600)


def write_read(x):
    ser.write(bytes(x, 'utf-8'))
    time.sleep(0.001)
    data = ser.readline()
    return data


while True:
    xv = '1'
    yv = '2'
    xvalue = StringVar()
    xvalue.set(write_read(xv))
    yvalue = StringVar()
    yvalue.set(write_read(yv))
    w = tk.Label(root, text="X").place(x=10, y=10)
    w1 = tk.Label(root, text="Y").place(x=10, y=40)
    display1 = Entry(root, font=("Courier", 16), justify='right', textvariable=xvalue).place(x=50, y=10)
    display2 = Entry(root, font=("Courier", 16), justify='right', textvariable=yvalue).place(x=50, y=40)
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
```

Comment: We have to see your code to be of any sort of help here. Assuming how your code works is going to do you no good. So please post some code ;D

Comment: I just posted the code. Please let me know if you got any advise. I send a number to arduino and based on the number, arduino send back a data.

Comment: Move `xvalue`, `yvalue`, `w`, `w1`, `display1`, and `display2` outside the loop. Also the reason for freeze is `time.sleep()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not worked with `serial` before so I dont know if this will work. The code looks functional to me. I changed your imports, then your function, and then removed somethings off the `while`. You where creating new widgets each time the `while` ran, so you might have created thousands of widgets already which might be why tkinter started freezing. Also the use `time.sleep()` will not update the GUI. So I have used `root.after()` for that.

**Quick solution:**
Move `xvalue`, `yvalue`, `w`, `w1`, `display1`, and `display2` outside the loop. So that the widget is created just once

**Different approach to avoid `time.sleep()`:**

```
from tkinter import tk
import serial

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
ser = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600)

def foo(x,caller):
    ser.write(bytes(x, 'utf-8'))
    def bar():
        data = ser.readline()
        if caller == 'x': # If called by x
            xvalue.set(data) # Then write to x
        else:  
            yvalue.set(data) # Else write to y
    root.after(1,bar) # Same as 0.001s 

xv = '1'
yv = '2'

xvalue = tk.StringVar()
yvalue = tk.StringVar()

w = tk.Label(root, text="X").place(x=10, y=10)
w1 = tk.Label(root, text="Y").place(x=10, y=40)

display1 = tk.Entry(root, font=("Courier", 16), justify='right', textvariable=xvalue).place(x=50, y=10)
display2 = tk.Entry(root, font=("Courier", 16), justify='right', textvariable=yvalue).place(x=50, y=40)

# Call functions initially
foo(xv,'x')
foo(yv,'y')

root.mainloop()
```

There is no need for using `StringVar` here, you could just use `delete` and `insert` methods from the entry widgets itself.